# Alamofire Put Request returns nothing

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to update values in mLab. I can successfully insert and fetch data but I can't update it. Below code returns HTTP 415 error. but nothing happens on database. I'm trying to fix it till weeks but nothing happens.

```
  let parameters_post: Parameters = [ "q" : "{\"uname\":\"e\"}",
        "$set": "{\"uname\":\"emree\"}",
        ]
    Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Cusers?apiKey=myApiKey", method: .post, parameters: parameters_post,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in
        print(response.result)
        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)

    }
}
```

and this is API document

```
    PUT /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}
Content-Type: application/json
Body: <JSON data>

Example setting "x" to 3 in the document with "_id" = 1234 (using jQuery):

$.ajax( { url: 'https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey&q={"_id":1234}',
          data: JSON.stringify( { "$set" : { "x" : 3 } } ),
          type: "PUT",
          contentType: "application/json" } );

Optional parameters:
[q=<query>][&m=true][&u=true]
```

Comment: From your code example you are doing a `.post` request, maybe try change `method` to `.put`

Comment: I tried that but didn't work :(

Comment: Hmmm, HTTP 415 is [`Unsupported Media Type`](https://httpstatuses.com/415) maybe check that your encoding correctly or that you are posting JSON?

Comment: I think problem is in json format but I took it from my register code and just add query part. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: Try this `..., encoding: .JSON` in your method instead of `URLEncoding.default`